# Can I display HTML in Error Messages control?

Tags: xpages

In my XPages application we are using Bootstrap for theming.

If I look at the alert component:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <strong>WARNING</strong> SYSTEM FAILURE. </div>
```

I see a  element is used.

Now in my XPages application I used something as followed:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage(javax.faces.application.FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "<strong>WARNING</strong> SYSTEM FAILURE", ""));
```

but this is displayed as text:

[image]

Is it somehow to make the Error Messages control display HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own message control like this:

```
<xp:panel styleClass="xspMessage"
    rendered="#{javascript:facesContext.getMessages().hasNext()}">
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="msg">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var v = new java.util.Vector();
var itr = facesContext.getMessages()     
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    var element:javax.faces.application.FacesMessage = itr.next();
    v.add(element.getSummary())
}
return v;}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:text escape="false" id="computedField1" value="#{msg}"  tagName="div">
        </xp:text>
    </xp:repeat>
</xp:panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to use CSS to format the error messages control output.